# Is the time of solution shorter as the initial data increases?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

I'm reading the book superlinear parabolic problems and I came across the following situation twice: given two initial data $u_0$ and $\underline{u_0}$ with $u_0\geq \underline{u_0}$, $u_0\neq \underline{u_0}$, and considering $u$ and $\underline{u}$ the solutions of the problem below corresponding to these data, then maximal existence time of the $\underline{u}$ is larger than $u$, this is $T_{\max}(\underline{u_0})\geq T_{\max}(u_0)$. Is this always true? Is it an already formalized theorem? Where can I find him? Below I put the studied problem, and the Lemma in which I saw this fact

[image]

Comment: i assume it must be maximum principle.  Can one show if the solution blows up it must blow up to $+\infty$ and not $-\infty$ ?    IF so maybe you can use one as a supersolution for the other to give desired...

Comment: I didn't quite understand, the maximum principle I know is about keeping the initial data inequalities for the corresponding solutions, so I can't see how to relate this to solution time, at least not from this version I know.